# Python 2.7 ignoring if not statement?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm creating a simple socket chatting application and I tried to make something that handles somebody terminating the client connected to the server, but it seems to ignore it and I get the connection forcibly closed by the remote host exception.

Here's some of the code

```
clients = []

class client(Thread):
    def __init__(self, socket, address):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = socket
        self.addr = address
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            msg = self.sock.recv(1024).decode()
            #This if not statement is ignored
            if not msg:
                clients.remove(socket)
                print str(adress[0]) + ":" + str(adress[1]) + " disconnected"
                quitm = str(adress[0]) + ":" + str(adress[1]) + " disconnected"
                for client in clients:
                    client.send(quitm.encode())
                socket.close()
                break
            print msg
            for client in clients:
                client.send(msg.encode())
```

I've been searching up for some solutions but haven't found any. Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the thing at the other end closes the connection normally, that is indicated by `recv()` returning zero bytes. However, if the thing at the other end terminates without closing the connection, that is considered an abnormal situation which indicated by `recv()` raising an exception. You need to use a `try`/`catch` block to handle that exception.